# Error installing Haxm for Android Studio

Tags: android, hyper-v, amd-processor, haxm

I have tried all the solutions I found on Google but I still get the same error when trying to install `Haxm for Android Studio`:

> "This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology(VT-x)"

I checked my BIOS and by default the technology is already enabled. (My pc has an AMD processor with Asus motherboard and it's called Secure Virtual Machine Mode)

When I tried

> "dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V"

in command prompt it gave me this error:

> "Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown"

I have uninstalled Avast because someone said it could affect the HAXM installation, it didn't work.

Can anyone help? I am completely clueless now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run HAXM on an AMD processor. Been there, tried it, doesn't work. HAXM is an Intel product and they can detect the presence or absence of their processor.

Try Genymotion with VirtualBox instead.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I really wish they could release something for AMD.

Comment: I understand your frustration, but from Intel's perspective they created HAXM for their customers and you aren't one of their customers. I don't know the technical details of how HAXM works, but it would be great for developers if they would open up the tool so that AMD could support it on their processors.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm), virtualization on AMD CPU is only supported on Linux:

> Many modern CPUs provide extensions for running virtual machines (VMs) more efficiently. Taking advantage of these extensions with the Android emulator requires some additional configuration of your development system, but can significantly improve the execution speed. Before attempting to use this type of acceleration, you should first determine if your development system’s CPU supports one of the following virtualization extensions technologies:
>
> > - Intel Virtualization Technology (VT, VT-x, vmx) extensions
> > - AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) extensions (only supported for Linux)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know my options now.